# Having a trouble with table reading on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm really new to programming and I've been trying to emulate the 'pandas.read_table' code from *Python for Data Analysis* book(the chapter on MovieLens 1M Data Set, pg.23ish). Below is the link to the file used for database and the images of jupyter notebook on which I've typed the codes. As you'll see there, I'm having a trouble with the data values not reading properly as it should, and I can't seem to figure out why. Your help will be much appreciated!

[Trouble screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmZBI.png)

[Database file](http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip)

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading data from a `.csv` file, use `pd.read_csv`.

If you want to use `pd.read_table`, you have to specify the delimiter as the comma with the argument `sep=','`. What is happening is that `pd.read_table` is trying to separate your input information at every `::`, but it looks like your data is separated by commas instead.

More information here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html

Comment: This is your answer!